# Can I use time extended variable in linear regression?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, independence, linear

I only have one independent variable to predict bankruptcy. 
As I can't use ARIMAX model so I decided to use linear regression. 
First, I use that one independent variable with one linear regression, 
but Its performance was bad.

Therefore, my Idea was that, How about make many variables through that one independent variable. This works like, ccf concept. I mean, assumed the one variable is X, then I moved 6month backward, Xt-6. Like this way 
I make Xt-6, xt-7 xt-8 ... xt-12. 
And then, I fitted multiple linear regression. bankruptcy = xt-6+ xt-7 + .. +xt-12. 
And it worked well. I got 0.7 adjusted R-square and I check VIF and It was 6.1 which was under 10.

However, I wondered, Is is ok to model regression like this? Thanks.